# How to avoid subset out of range when running a delete rows with variable

Tags: vba, excel, outofrangeexception

I know this may have been asked in various formats, however I am completely new to coding and don't understand how to apply it to this function.

I keep getting a **subscript out of range error** message when running this vba.

```
Sub KeepOnlyAtSymbolRows()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    lastRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Set rng = ws.Range("A1:A" & lastRow)

    With rng
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>*International SBU*"
        .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    End With
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
End Sub
```

For context my sheet at the moment is 178 rows long and goes up to AK however the number of rows will vary each update the number of columns won't

Comment: On which line do you have the error message?

Comment: I'm not sure that's the problem, it's just every time i try to run it i end up getting the error message, have i set part of the code up wrong. There are also some breaks in the text but not in column A

Comment: I didn't mean on which line of your Excel sheet, I meant on which line of code ;)

Comment: When the error message comes up it highlights the whole vba so i'm assuming that means it's all wrong. I think the error must be driven by the set rng line

Comment: The whole code??? I never saw that!^^ Generally, it is only one row at a time... So check that you have a sheet name "Sheet1", because your code doesn't seem that wrong!

Comment: Haha thanks, i'd named it a different sheet however when i was on the VBA screen it called it sheet1 then in brackets the name. I thought the sheet 1 would still pull it through. Like i said i'm very new to coding, most the time my job doesn't need it and never used it at university

Comment: No problem, I'll post an answer to explain different ways to call a sheet, if you could accept it to mark the issue as solved, that would be great! ;)

Comment: Yep absolutely thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful when you hard code the name of your sheets like this :

```
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
```

Because if you change the name in Excel, you'll have to it also in your code (you'll find it out pretty shortly with an error message)

So **different ways to call/reference a sheet** :

### Classical, with Sheet's name

```
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
```

### Using index

```
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
```

### Using Sheet's object name

```
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheet1
```

**That name won't change, even if you rename the Sheet directly in Excel!**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are not working with table. If that is the case then try this :

```
Sub KeepOnlyAtSymbolRows()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim lastRow As Long

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

lastRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set rng = ws.Range("A1:A" & lastRow)
Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'to stop prompting for deletion
With rng
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>*International SBU*"
    .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
End With
ws.AutoFilterMode = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```