# Converting values to LBS -Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to convert the numbers form different units to LBS using the code below:

I have no idea what's wrong with this simple code below but it just doesn't gives any output :

The data is in Table format with Top 2 rows been freezed.

Screenshot is attached below

```
Option Explicit

Sub ConvertToLBS()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim wk As Worksheet
    Dim str As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim strq, strs As Double
    Dim FinalRow As Long
    Set wk = Sheets(1)
    FinalRow = wk.Range("B900000").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 To FinalRow

            str = wk.Range("R" & i).Text
            str = Trim(str)

            strq = wk.Range("Q" & i).Value

            If str = "POUNDS" Then
                strs = strq * 1
                wk.Range("S" & i).Value = strs
            Else: End If

        If str = "YARDS" Then
            strs = strq * 1688.55
            wk.Range("S" & i).Value = strs
        Else: End If

        If str = "KILOGRAMS" Then
            strs = strq * 2.20462
            wk.Range("S" & i).Value = strs
        Else: End If

        If str = "TONS" Then
            strs = strq * 2000
            wk.Range("S" & i).Value = strs
        Else: End If

        If str = "GALLONS" Then
            strs = strq * 8.34
            wk.Range("S" & i).Value = strs
        Else: End If

    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: You should use a `Select Case` rather that a lot of `If` for better coding and readability. Did you use break points to see how the code works? You could add `Option Compare Text` at the top of your module to avoid failing a test because of the capitalisation (case) of the strings!

Comment: You have assigned the first worksheet to your variable `wk`: `Set wk = Sheets(1)`. On the screen attached I can see that the data are in the second worksheet. So, change this line to `Set wk = Sheets(2)`. Or even better assign it by name: `Set wk = Sheets("BR Mailing List_12-4-15 (3)")`.

Comment: @mielk No it's the First sheet only I have created the `Controls` sheet after the BR_Mailing... Sheet

Comment: @RohanK : Mkay, you may have confuse 2 different type of referencing a sheet. `Sheets(1)` and `Sheet1` are far different things, `Sheets(1)` will be the first sheet on the left in the bottom ribbon, and `Sheet1` would indeed be the first sheet that you created, see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31287725/how-to-avoid-subset-out-of-range-when-running-a-delete-rows-with-variable/31288273#31288273 I included the name of the worksheet in my answer, I leave it to you to correct it to apply it to the right sheet once it is working properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your If ... Else were fouled up; possibly with those colons attempting to shorthand the code. I would suggest changing to a [Select Case statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278665.aspx).  They are really designed for conditional checks like this.

```
Sub ConvertToLBS()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim wk As Worksheet
    Dim str As String
    Dim i As Long, FinalRow As Long
    Dim strq As Double, strs As Double

    Set wk = Sheets(1)

    With wk
        FinalRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 To FinalRow
            str = Trim(UCase(.Range("R" & i).Text))
            strq = .Range("Q" & i).Value
            strs = 0

            Select Case str
                Case "POUNDS"
                    strs = strq * 1
                Case "YARDS"
                    strs = strq * 1688.55
                Case "KILOGRAMS"
                    strs = strq * 2.20462
                Case "TONS"
                    strs = strq * 2000
                Case "GALLONS"
                    strs = strq * 8.34
                Case Else
                    'do nothing; not covered
                    Debug.Print str
            End Select
            .Range("S" & i) = strs
        Next i
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried your code I don't think there's any thing wrong but it is not working I don't get any output I have attached the screenshot of the data.

Comment: The numbers in column Q are text-that-look-like numbers. That is why they are all marked as potential errors. Select column Q and set to General cell number format then run Data, Text to Columns, Fixed width, Finish.

Comment: Ohh.. Yes it's text. Thanks I will do it soon

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in comments :

```
Option Compare Text
Option Explicit

Sub ConvertToLBS()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim wk As Worksheet
    Dim str As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim strq, strs As Double
    Dim FinalRow As Long
    'Set wk = Sheets(1)
    Set wk = Sheets("BR Mailing List_12-4-15 (3)")
    FinalRow = wk.Range("R" & wk.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To FinalRow
        str = Trim(wk.Range("R" & i).Value)
        strq = CDbl(wk.Range("Q" & i).Value)
        Select Case str
            Case Is = "POUNDS"
                strs = strq * 1
            Case Is = "YARDS"
                strs = strq * 1688.55
            Case Is = "KILOGRAMS"
                strs = strq * 2.20462
            Case Is = "TONS"
                strs = strq * 2000
            Case Is = "GALLONS"
                strs = strq * 8.34
        End Select
        wk.Range("S" & i).Value = CDbl(strs)
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't works please have a look at the screenshot attached in the question.

Comment: @RohanK : Ok I saw the screenshot, but I don't understand how this doesn't work (as I already included `CDbl` when reading column Q)? Could you detail a bit more? Is there an error? Is there an output in column S? Is it the wrong one??

Comment: Thanks there were two main problems with my sheet first was that the data in col Q wasn't formatted right some of them were text and second as you said the difference between `Sheet1` and `Sheets(1)`

Comment: ok, but as I said, the data that was formatted as text wasn't an issue with what I proposed as I convert it using `CDbl()`. ;)

Comment: No it has to be a number to be converted to a double I don't think you can convert text to Double because if it has `34, 678` instead of `34,678` it will give me a `Type Mismatch Error`

Comment: If you have a space, it might throw an error indeed! But I didn't saw that in your screenshot so I didn't understand why there was an error, now I get it! Thx ;)